# Constant declaration with 2 types in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, constants, declaration

I have two models: `CarModel` and `BikeModel`. They are identical except for the internal data. I prefer to fill in two files instead of one.

And so I wonder if there's a simple way to declare a constant with 2 types. In my case, `let vehicle: Car OR Bike`.

I've seen some possibilities on SO with `protocol` or `enum` but I'm looking for something very simple otherwise I'll have to copy/paste `VehicleDetailsView()`. Something like: `let vehicle: Car OR Bike`, `let vehicle: Car || Bike` or maybe `let vehicle: (Car, Bike)`. Do you think it's possible?

Here's a part of code for better understanding:

```
struct VehiclesView: View {
    @State var vehiclesSort = "All"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Buttons
            if vehiclesSort == "Cars" {
                ForEach(cars) { car in
                    VehicleDetailsView(vehicle: car) // Of type Car
                }
            } else if vehiclesSort == "Bikes" {
                ForEach(bikes) { bike in
                    VehicleDetailsView(vehicle: bike) // Of type Bike
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VehicleDetailsView: View {
    let vehicle: Car /* OR Bike */

    var body: some View {
        // Content
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Create an intermediary model that can be initialized with a bike or a car?

Comment: What could it look like?

Comment: `struct VehicleDetailsViewModel { let title: String, etc. }; extension VehicleDetailsViewModel { init(with car: Car) {self.title = car.name }; init(with bike: Bike) { self.title = bike.name }}` ?

Comment: READ THIS: I really don't understand why some people on SO close questions. Most of the time the linked question isn't helping. In my case, I still don't know what to do. This is so frustrating!

Comment: let vehicle: Car || Bike is the exact definion of inheritence but if you are adamant about not using it there no such thing as let vehicle: Car || Bike

Comment: @MehmetKaranlık Actually, I'm using `protocol`. It's easier than I thought, I just had to add `var something: String { get }`.

Comment: @Alexnnd yes its pretty easy, just define common properties. But for example if you want to use this protocol on view u cant reach other properties if concrete type has another property thats not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

no, that is not possible. what you're describing is an enum. you're gonna wanna create an enum for this.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an example to understand how to implement this solution?